# Reschedule inexactRepeating alarm with pendingIntent from sharedPreferenceChange

Tags: android, settings, alarm, android-pendingintent

I'm developing a test app to learn Android in which I need to fire up a service periodically to update some data. I'm using the `AlarmManager` with a `BroadcastReceiver` to set the alarm and it successfully updates the data with the default interval but I'd like to have this interval as a user defined value.
 
I currently have the following code to register the alarm:

In the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The receiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = BootReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive method");
        AlarmCreator.setAlarm(context, intent);

    }
}
```

The actual alarm:

```
public static void setAlarm(Context context, Intent intent){
    Log.d(TAG, "Setting alarm");
    // I need the context here
    context.startService(new Intent(context, RefreshService.class));

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    long interval = Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("interval",
            Long.toString(DEFAULT_INTERVAL)));
    // Here
    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(context, -1,
            new Intent(context, RefreshService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // And here
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (interval == 0) {
        alarmManager.cancel(operation);
        Log.d(TAG, "Cancelling alarm");
    } else {
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, operation);
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting alarm with interval: " + interval);
    }
}
```

### What I've tried

I know that using the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` I can execute code when a preference is updated, the problem is that in order to set the alarm I need to have a `Context` which the Preference class doesn't provide. I am aware of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` the problem is that they can return null depending on the life cycle of the Preference activity.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        if (key.equals("interval")){
                // Since I'm not using the intent I can just simply pass null.
                AlarmCreator.setAlarm(??,null);
            }

    }

}
```

### The question

What should I pass to `AlarmCreator.setAlarm(Content,intent)` so that the alarm gets correctly canceled or updated? Is it even possible? Maybe there's a better approach that I'm missing.

### Additional info

I just started learning Android development but I've spent a good amount of time reading the documentation and I just couldn't figure out how to do it.
There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906618/how-to-reschedule-alarm-manager-on-preference-change) which helped to get me on track but I found the answer too vague for my understanding at the moment.

Any Ideas would be appreciated. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I posted this question and now I feel stupid because the answer was obvious. 
Call `getActivity()` and pass that for the context. 
You can call `getActivity()` in any `fragment` or `this` if you need the context inside an Activity. 
Keep in mind that **the kind of context you pass matters**, you can get different results if you use the activity's context instead of the application context (`getActivity().getApplicationContext()`) in certains situations. 
Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298955/2940990) to learn more.